# Parse text file data to send a mail in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to PERL. I want to create a PERL Script that could send mail by taking all required fields from an input file present at desktop and can send a mail to everyone in mailing list (separated by comma) accordingly. Contents of my input data file is as follows:

- Recipients are enclosed between tags TO & ENDTO.
- Subject of mail is enclosed between SUBJECT & ENDSUBJECT.
- Body of mail is enclosed between BODY & ENDBODY.

Sample data file :

TO 
rahul@example.com,you@everyone.com 
ENDTO

SUBJECT 
Weekly status snapshot for WW-5 
ENDSUBJECT

BODY 
Hi All, 
Weekly progress snapshot for this week will be taken on Thursday, 30 Jan at the end of the day. ( Please update your status before the snapshot) 
Use work week number as 5 for this week's updates . 
Note : If you want any additional data to be picked up ( or dropped ) from your sheets, do work with me so that status collation script can be updated to do this . 
Thanks , 
-Ram 
ENDBODY

- Till now I'm using a code that takes inputs from two different files ("message.txt" & "recipients.txt") and sends mail accordingly. But now I want to parse data from a single file separated by tag fields for recipients, body and subject.

```
    $mailprog = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";

    my $file1 = 'message';
    open my $ifh1, '<', $file1;
    local $/ = undef;
    my $contents = $ifh1;

    my $file2 = 'recipients';
    open my $ifh2, '<', $file2;
    local $/ = undef;
    my $recip = $ifh2; 

    close( $ifh2 );
    close( $ifh1 );

    $subject= "Weekly status snapshot for WW-3";
    open(MAIL, "|$mailprog -t");
    print MAIL "To: $recip \n";
    print MAIL "bcc: rahul.agarwal\@everyone.com\n";
    print MAIL "From: rahul.agarwal\@everyone.com\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n";
    print MAIL "$contents";
    close(MAIL);
```

Comment: Crossposed from [perlmonks.org](https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1229334)

Comment: Where is the question in your post?

Comment: There is *no* "PERL". `Perl` is the language; `perl` is the name of the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Gist of the implementation approach: use `..` bi-stable operator with regexes defining the start and end conditions.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Generate regexes for section keywords
my @sections = qw(TO SUBJECT BODY);
my %keywords = map {
    (
     "$_"    => qr/^$_$/,
     "END$_" => qr/^END$_$/
    )} @sections;

my($to, $subject, @body);
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    if      (/$keywords{TO}/../$keywords{ENDTO}/) {
        # skip keyword lines
        next if /$keywords{TO}|$keywords{ENDTO}/;
        $to = $_;
    } elsif  (/$keywords{SUBJECT}/../$keywords{ENDSUBJECT}/) {
        # skip keyword lines
        next if /$keywords{SUBJECT}|$keywords{ENDSUBJECT}/;
        $subject = $_;
    } elsif  (/$keywords{BODY}/../$keywords{ENDBODY}/) {
        if      (/$keywords{BODY}/) {
            # skip keyword line
        } elsif (/$keywords{ENDBODY}/) {
            # mail is done... send it
            print "To: ${to}\n";
            print "Bcc: rahul.agarwal\@everyone.com\n";
            print "From: rahul.agarwal\@everyone.com\n";
            print "Subject: ${subject}\n";
            print "\n";
            print "$_\n" foreach (@body);
        } else {
            # body text line
            push(@body, $_);
        }
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Output with your test example:

```
# add "| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t" after command to actually send it...
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.txt
To: rahul@example.com,you@everyone.com
Bcc: rahul.agarwal@everyone.com
From: rahul.agarwal@everyone.com
Subject: Weekly status snapshot for WW-5

Hi All, Weekly progress snapshot for this week will be taken on Thursday, 30 Jan at the end of the day. ( Please update your status before the snapshot)
Use work week number as 5 for this week's updates .
Note : If you want any additional data to be picked up ( or dropped ) from your sheets, do work with me so that status collation script can be updated to do this .
Thanks ,
-Ram
```